# SSL Subdomain redirects to Original Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, dns

I have a domain.com (main domain), works perfectly with https://domain.com
I also have a Subdomain  store.domain.com. It works good only with HTTP, such as http://store.domain.com. When I add HTTPS to subdomain, it automatically redirects to Main domain. Such as https//:store.domain.com --->redirects--> https://domain.com

**I have a Wildcard SSL for domain.com**

Any help how to make https//:store.domain.com work properly with HTTPS  without  being redirected to main domain ?

Comment: Post your redirect code

Comment: I have no redirect code. For subdomain domain. I set up Magento store and set up all necessary HTTPS settings I admin panel.

Comment: then how do you send user? if you will show a link <a href=""> it should work.
It means that you redirect user with a header location or with javascript window location

Comment: I believe it is <?php

header('Location: https://example.com');
exit;
?>